# Expected Identifier but got '='

Tags: solidity, remix

Trying to add a struct object to a mapping, however the compiler gives error that expected identifier.
Here is my code snippet

```
contract Structs {

    struct User {
        string name;
        uint256 score;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    mapping(address => User) userList;
    User user1 = new User({name : "Jimmy", score : 1 , balance : 100});
    userList[msg.sender] = user1;
}
```

It gives the error at the following line of code

```
 userList[msg.sender] = user1;
```

How do we add new struct object to a mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the code should have been inside a function or so. Here is the updated one, which works fine

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract Structs {

    struct User {
        string name;
        uint256 score;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    mapping(address => User) userList;   

    function createUser() external {    
        User memory user1 = User({name : "Liquidus", score : 1 , balance : 100});
        userList[msg.sender] = user1;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function in which you can add the item to the struct. It is not possible to do so outside of a function.

For your example you could do the following:

```js
contract Structs {

    struct User {
        string name;
        uint256 score;
        uint256 balance;
    }

    mapping(address => User) userList;
    
    function addUser() public {
        User memory user1 = User({name: "Jimmy", score: 1, balance: 100});
        userList[msg.sender] = user1;
    }
}
```

The `addUser` function can be called from the constructor if you need this to happen on contract deployment.

In general you should not use `new` with struct items (this is reserved for contract creation and arrays).

You can find more information in the Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#structs